# Using shellinabox as a remote SSH client tool to connect to different portal

Tags: linux, ssh

We are currently working in creating an online Access Manager tool which will securely save our servers shell credentials securely and will allow admins to access remote SSH servers without knowing the credentials. We have most of the part sorted out but the only thing which is missing is SSH server connectivity through web-browser. We are lookginf or a solution like shellinabox but only difference is that we should be able to pass IPaddress, User ID and Password remotely to start SSH session.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Why not have the administrators log in with their personal SSH keys? Then, if you ever want to revoke their access, just change the `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Idea behind the solution is to build a Access manager where access are controlled after taking required approvals. It's a required governance model.